# Facebook application error- Access Token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have made new Facebook application, and when I am trying to allow "post to profile", I am getting this error: 
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in /home/mimota/public_html/gamingapp.com/test/src/base_facebook.php on line 1024

Thats part of the base_facebook.php file:

http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2263
I have marked there where is line 1024

I will really appriciate if some one could figure out whats wrong here, because I have no clue..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a URL of the following format to log into facebook:

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=288229791195831&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&type=user_agent&display=popup&scope=publish_stream,user_photos,read_stream,email

They will give you a token back which you will use when you send requests:

> For example to see get the main photo URL use:
>   https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture&access_token=THE_TOKEN_YOU_GOT_BACK

To post to wall replace `/me/picture` with whatever you need to post (sth like /me/wall)